# Kill them with Darkwood Scythe: [dyndns], [dynamic-ip], and [dynamic-dns]

Tags: discussion

Before I go flag mad, let's discuss the topic of dynamic IP addresses. There are a lot of questions that deal with dynamic IP addresses. Most of them are in the context of home networks. Some appear to be smaller businesses that do not have "business class" internet connections. See for yourself:

[dyndns](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dyndns)

[dynamic-ip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-ip)

[dynamic-dns](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-dns)

### Question:

Do we commit genocide on all tags and tagged questions that involve dynamic IPS?

**...OR...**

Do we keep dynamic IP tags and simply take each question on a case by case basis?

<sub><sub>If the latter, we'll need to start taking donations to buy jumbo-sized Advil containers for each of the mods. I'm up to 45 flags a day now...</sub></sub>

Answer (score 4):

`dyndns` is a company and should probably be killed off (the tag, not the company) but otherwise you're thinking too narrowly.

`dynamic-ip` and `dynamic-dns` can both apply to internal networks, not just the external connection. e.g. Workstations will generally have a dynamic IP address and the DNS server will be updated dynamically by either the client or the DHCP service.

Comment: "Wow, I don't like DynDNS but that's harsh... ohhhhh, I get it."

Comment: And yes, thanks for the perspective. I get it now. Time to get 'a flaggin'.

Comment: @WesleyDavid, I did say the TAG, not the company should probably be killed off.

Answer (score 3):

Whoah, you are one seriously hardcore mean motherlover.

Dynamic IP addresses are something that we've all had to deal with, and ways to work with them are a totally normal part of business.

Just wait till we start getting more Carrier Grade NAT questions...

If the *only* thing concerning you in them is Dynamic IP's, just leave them be. If there are *other* things wrong besides dynamic IPs, feel free to deal with them on a case by case basis.

Comment: I've had to deal with them, but only ever with home offices so I don't count that as "professional SysAdmin". **No!** Believe it or not, today was my *very* first interaction with a small business that used an internet connection that had a dynamic IP at a real office. What a coincidence.

Comment: +1 - Dynamic IPs in an of themselves aren't a *bad* thing, a lot of companies have dynamic IPs for their workstations, and dynamic DNS updates go hand-in-hand with that.  [tag:dhcp] is probably a *better* tag for some of these questions, but there's nothing inherently foul about (properly configured) dynamic IP & dynamic DNS environments

Answer (score 1):

We use DynDNS at work (across lots of small offices) for a number of things (cheap public DNS, DNS filtering etc.) but I can't think of a question regarding DynDNS that would be appropriate for ServerFault.

[dynamic-ip](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-ip) and [dynamic-dns](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-dns) seem to be separate but require constant pruning of off-topic questions.